# Error while getting value of the field

Tags: c#, class, serialization, field

Ok, hello there. I have a class, in which i want to write usiversal saver. So, this class may be inherited, we can not just get some values from file and put them into fields. I did that in this way:

```
virtual public void Load(string filename) {
    if (!File.Exists(filename)) throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.");
    FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filename);
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    object loaded = bf.Deserialize(fs);
    if (!(loaded is Application)) throw new TypeLoadException("File doesn't consist any applications.");
    Application temp = loaded as Application;
    fs.Close();
    foreach (System.Reflection.MemberInfo item in temp.GetType().GetMembers()) { 
        object value = temp.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name).GetValue(temp, null);
        this.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name).SetValue(this, value, null);
    }
}
```

But, at the line `object value ...` i got an error:

[image]

Ok, i thought it happened cause i didn't specified any type (but `object`?...)
So, i tried to did that:

```
foreach (System.Reflection.MemberInfo item in temp.GetType().GetMembers()) { 
    Type varType = item.GetType();
    object value = temp.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name).GetValue(temp, null) as varType;
    this.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name).SetValue(this, value, null);
}
```

Now error is `The type or namespace 'varType' could not be found`. Help me please! Thanks.

P.S. MonoDevelop, Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: i can't found anything that could be `null` :(

Comment: The result of `GetProperty` is `null` if there is no property with the provided named.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna get `Properties`, why are you using `GetMembers` ? Not all members of a class are property, but you are treating them like they were.

```
foreach (var prop in temp.GetType().GetProperties()) { 
    object value = prop.GetValue(temp, null);
    prop.SetValue(this, value, null);
}
```

Comment: Ok, i hastened. `temp.GetType().GetProperties()` returns empty list, but i have 3 properties in my class.

Comment: Thanks anyway, i used `GetFields()` and now it works :D